# used #pragma pack in c but could not understand

Tags: c

I have written a code using #pragma directive to align but I could not understand how alignment is occuring.
I am using gcc on ubuntu.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MALE 0;
#define FEMALE 1;
#define SINGLE 0;
#define MARRIED 1;
#pragma pack(3);

int main()
{
    struct emp
    {
        unsigned gender :1;
        unsigned mar:1;
        unsigned hobby:1;
        unsigned scheme :1;
    };
    struct emp e;
    e.gender=MALE;
    e.mar=SINGLE;
    e.hobby=1;
    e.scheme=1;
    printf("size of %d",sizeof(e));
    return 0;
}
```

when I use #pragma pack as 1, size comes out to be 1, #pragma pack as 2 size comes out as 2, and for 3 it's 4.

Can you tell me what's happening? If I don't use it still 4 comes.

So what's the difference between `#pragma pack(1)` and `#pragma pack(2)`?

Comment: 3 is not valid for a for `pragma pack`. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: i want to know that when i write #pragma pack(1) it set first bits and atart second from next one what if i write #pragma(2) , whats the difference

Comment: You do not want the semi-colons at the end of the `#define` lines.  You probably don't want the semi-colon at the end of the `#pragma` line either.

Answer (score 3):

`3` is not a valid argument of `#pragma pack` directive.

Valid values are `1`, `2`, `4`, `8` and `16`, according to [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/compiler_ref/pragma_pack.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `#pragma' directive is the method specified by the C standard for providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is conveyed in the language itself.

`#pragma` pack specifies packing alignment for structure, union, and class members.

Valid values are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of any of the above mentioned values or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller.

Refer to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/compiler/ref/rnpgpack.htm) for more details.

Also, some info on structure packing below from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9705)

**What is structure packing?**

Some times it is mandatory to avoid padded bytes among the members of structure. For example, reading contents of ELF file header or BMP or JPEG file header. We need to define a structure similar to that of the header layout and map it. However, care should be exercised in accessing such members. Typically reading byte by byte is an option to avoid misaligned exceptions. There will be hit on performance.

Most of the compilers provide non standard extensions to switch off the default padding like pragmas or command line switches. Consult the documentation of respective compiler for more details.

```
i want to know that when i write #pragma pack(1) it set first bits and atart second from next one what if i write #pragma(2) , whats the difference
```

To answer this, when you set #pragma to 2, if the data residing in the structure is less than 2 bytes, it alignment remains the same. But, if it is more than 2 bytes (say a 4 byte integer), it will be split and aligned at 2 byte boundaries.

Comment: whats the difference between #pragma pack(1) and #pragma pack(2) when i applied in my code and retrieves answer , what is happening bit or byte wise because of which size of struct emp e is changing

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `#pragma pack(1)` and `#pragma pack(2)` is that in the first case you say that your struct can start on any address.

With  `#pragma pack(2)` you say that the start address must be evenly divisible by 2 (an even address). The compiler does this by then saying that the struct has a size 2 (by padding it with some unused space).

If you create an array of `emp`, like `emp a[10]`, the `sizeof(emp)` is also the distance between each element of the array. That's why the compiler rounds the size up to the next multiple of the `#pragma pack` value.